# findOne property not defined in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a model using Sequelize and mysql db.I am trying to post to '/students/register' it keeps giving me an error saying findOne is not a function. I tried requiring my sql but it's not working ..I also tried a different function like findAll and still not working. what seems to be the problem.Thanks

**models/Students.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../database/db')

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Student = sequelize.define(
        'student', {
            id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            email: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            password: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            created: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
            }
        }, {
            timestamps: false
        });
    module.exports = Student;
};
```

**database/db.js**

```
   const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize('canavs', 'root', 'root', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8889,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    operatorAliases: false,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 3000,
        idle: 10000
    }
})
// sequelize.import('./models/Students')
module.exports = sequelize;
```

**index.js**

```
const Student_Info = require('./models/Students')
const db = require('./database/db')



// app.use('/students', Student)

app.get('/getName', (req, res) => {
    Student_Info.findOne({
            where: {
                id: 1
            }
        })
        .then((student) => {
            res.json(student.name);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
                res.send('error' + err)
            }

        )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `student` model definition, you didnt return the definition.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Student = sequelize.define(
        'student', {
            ...
        }, {
            timestamps: false
        });
    return Student; // You have to return the Student model in its definition
};
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

Lets keep it simple export only student model no need to export Sequelize/sequelize(db) bcoz you can require it instead of exporting require it !!

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../database/db');

const Student = connection.define('student', {

    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        validate: {
            isAlpha: true
        }
    }
});


module.exports = Student;
```